# Connect to the parameter server from Windows?

Tags: ros, param-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

I am developing the system that user input is done in windows, and ubuntu + ROS system controls a robot based on the user input.

What I need is only to read/write parameters on ubuntu ROS's parameter server.

Since I use diamondback, I have difficult to develop ROS node in Windows. (Several library is linked in the program in Windows, and I cannot compile a few ROS nodes in Electric. )

Is there any way I can connect to the parameter server from Windows?

Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12207/connect-to-the-parameter-server-from-windows?/) by [SeongUk Han](https://answers.ros.org/users/847/seonguk-han/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Communication with the parameter server works through ordinary XMLRPC. Just use an XMLRPC library to communicate with the parameter server. The API is described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Parameter%20Server%20API). A few basics including a Python example to communicate with the master are described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SeongUk Han](https://answers.ros.org/users/847/seonguk-han/) on 2011-12-05**:
Thanks a lot!